# Paged list isn't working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I did the Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#) tutorial by Rick Anderson, is a catalog of products, is already working, but, since i added a long list of products, now i need a pagedList to get just a number of products per page, looking around i found an example but isn't working, to my project i added on the Models file this class named IPagedList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Presupuestos.Models
{
    public interface IPagedList
    {
        int ItemCount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        int PageCount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        int PageIndex
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        int PageSize
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        bool IsPreviousPage
        {
            get;
        }

        bool IsNextPage
        {
            get;
        }
    }

    public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>, IPagedList
    {
    }

    public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
    {
        private List<Productos> list;
        private int p;
        private int p_2;

        public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
        {
            this.ItemCount = source.Count();
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.PageIndex = index;
            this.AddRange(source.Skip(index * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
            this.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)this.ItemCount / this.PageSize);
        }

        public PagedList(List<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
        {
            this.ItemCount = source.Count();
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.PageIndex = index;
            this.AddRange(source.Skip(index * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
        }

        public PagedList(List<Productos> list, int p, int p_2)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.list = list;
            this.p = p;
            this.p_2 = p_2;
        }

        public int ItemCount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int PageCount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int PageIndex
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int PageSize
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool IsPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 0);
            }
        }

        public bool IsNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex + 1) * PageSize <= ItemCount;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Pagination
    {
        public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
        {
            return new PagedList<T>(source, index, pageSize);
        }

        public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int index)
        {
            return new PagedList<T>(source, index, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, i added another class named HTMLHelpers.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using Presupuestos.Models;

namespace Presupuestos.Models
{
    public static class ListPaging
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Paging(this HtmlHelper html, IPagedList pagedList, string url, string pagePlaceHolder)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // only show paging if we have more items than the page size
            if (pagedList.ItemCount > pagedList.PageSize)
            {
                sb.Append("<ul class=\"paging\">");
                if (pagedList.IsPreviousPage && pagedList.PageIndex != 1)
                {
                    // previous link
                    sb.Append("<li class=\"prev\"><a href=\"");
                    sb.Append(url.Replace(pagePlaceHolder, (pagedList.PageIndex - 1).ToString()));
                    sb.Append("\" title=\"Go to Previous Page\">prev</a></li>");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < pagedList.PageCount; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("<li>");
                    if (i == pagedList.PageIndex)
                    {
                        sb.Append("<span>").Append((i + 1).ToString()).Append("</span>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append("<a href=\"");
                        sb.Append(url.Replace(pagePlaceHolder, (i + 1).ToString()));
                        sb.Append("\" title=\"Go to Page ").Append((i + 1).ToString());
                        sb.Append("\">").Append((i + 1).ToString()).Append("</a>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</li>");
                }
                if (pagedList.IsNextPage)
                {
                    // next link
                    sb.Append("<li class=\"next\"><a href=\"");
                    sb.Append(url.Replace(pagePlaceHolder, (pagedList.PageIndex + 1).ToString()));
                    sb.Append("\" title=\"Go to Next Page\">next</a></li>");
                }
                sb.Append("</ul>");
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is the view file, i just added the @using presupuestos.models and the last html.paging at the end:

```
@model IEnumerable<Presupuestos.Models.Productos>        
@using Presupuestos.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Productos";
}

<h2>Catalogo de Productos</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Agregar Producto", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Marca
        </th>
        <th>
            Codigo
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombre
        </th>
        <th>
            Envase
        </th>
        <th>
            Presentación
        </th>
        <th>
            Linea
        </th>
        <th>
            Categoria
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.marca)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.codigo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.envase)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.presentación)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.linea)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.categoria)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Borrar", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<div>
@Html.Paging(new PagedList<Productos>(ViewData.Model.ToList(),1,10), Url.Action("Index","Index", new { page = "PAGENUM" }), "PAGENUM")
</div>
```

Hope you can help me, i have been stuck with this for one day, just last friday i started using mvc3, the good thing was what my boss needs is what is on the tutorial, but, now that i wanted to do this extra thing (pagedlist) i'm really lost!!

Comment: Please could you say a bit more specifically what isn't working.

Comment: And also it would help if you could post where the IPagedList example is from.

Comment: I debug and run and i can see the list with all the saved records on the database but the pagedlist isn't working, doesn't appear at the bottom of the page, i got the code from here http://forums.asp.net/t/1678594.aspx/1/10 with the corrections made by some contributors to the post

Comment: Are you trying to create your own pagedlist? why don't you try https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList?

Comment: I was trying to do this example before but i couldn't do it :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if in this line

```
@Html.Paging(new PagedList<Productos>(ViewData.Model.ToList(),1,10), Url.Action("Index","Index", new { page = "PAGENUM" }), "PAGENUM")
```

you are hardcoding the current page index to be 1.

I'd guess that in your Index action method you need might want to have something representing your current page that you can pass through to your view, and replace the hardcoded 1 with that.

e.g.

```
public void Index(int page = 1)
{
    // ... set up your view model
    // ...
    // ...

    // page is added to the url by your paging helper.
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in the view...

```
@Html.Paging(new PagedList<Productos>(ViewData.Model.ToList(),@ViewBag.CurrentPage,10), Url.Action("Index","Index", new { page = "PAGENUM" }), "PAGENUM")
```

Comment: I edited the change to look like this `public ViewResult Index(int page = 1)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
            return View(db.Productos.ToList());
        }` and paste what you wrote in the view but still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said in your comment, that the paged list doesn't appear at the bottom of the page, I'd really recommend doing some debugging and seeing which code paths are actually executing.  But anyway we can maybe guess the following...

First step is to put a breakpoint in the `ListPaging.Paging` and check it's actually getting called.  If it is, and nothing at all is getting appended to your StringBuilder, then perhaps

```
if (pagedList.ItemCount > pagedList.PageSize)
{
     // ...
```

is not evaluating to true.  I'm assuming there's more items in your list than 10, so it should be true.  So maybe the reason this isn't evaluating to true is because neither value is being set.

The constructor that you added looks dubious:

```
public PagedList(List<Productos> list, int p, int p_2)
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    this.list = list;
    this.p = p;
    this.p_2 = p_2;
}
```

None of the properties that PagedList uses actually get set in here.  what's the point of this constructor?  What are `p` and `p_2`?  If this constructor is being called, then ItemCount and PageSize will have no value.  I'd suggest getting rid of it and letting the other constructors be called.

Comment: Yeah! i get rid of it, i'm searching for a new way to do it, thanks!